# UWP exception in release mode only

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-standard

I'm trying to load XmlReader to System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed and it cause an exception only in release mode but work in debug mode

the loading code

```
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(stringXML), new XmlReaderSettings { Async = true, IgnoreWhitespace = true, IgnoreComments = true }))
{
    System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed feed = System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader);
}
```

the exception

```
System.Reflection.MissingRuntimeArtifactException: ‘Cannot retrieve a MethodInfo for this delegate because the method it targeted (System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeedFormatter.DefaultUriParser(XmlUriData, Uri&)) was not enabled for metadata using the Dynamic attribute. For more information, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=616868’
```

and the xml content https://mspoweruser.com/feed

Comment: When you build the release version then you're testing the .NET Native build of your app.  Very different, it is an ahead-of-time compiler, the one that the Store server uses before delivering the binaries to the user of your app.  Reflection is the one feature that tends to not work well in that scenario, google ".net native compile errors" to learn how to use rd.xml

Comment: Did you follow the link in the error message? It takes you to a wizard that writes the rd.xml for you.

Comment: i did and i thought it's about stuff in UWP only but that code crush in another project built on .net standard until Hans Passant pointed out that i should search for .net native compile errors and i knew then that it affect everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding this code to the Default.rd.xml file fixes the problem

```
<Library Name="SyndicationFeed">
  <Assembly Name="System.ServiceModel.Syndication" Activate="Required All" Browse="Required All" Serialize="Required All" Dynamic="Required All" />
  <Namespace Name="System.ServiceModel.Syndication" Dynamic="Required All" />
</Library>
```

after `</Application>` and before `</Directives>`